# How to apply a computed loss to a graph?

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and trying to code a toy discriminator problem. The way I have it set up, the loss is calculated from the `expert_actions` and the `novice_actions`. However, I am running an error when I am trying to optimize using the computed loss. The error is `ValueError: No variables to optimize.` I do understand that I am getting the error because there is no `feed_dict`. However, I do not know the solution to this.

```py
class discriminator:
    def __init__(self,n_actions, learning_rate):
        self.n_actions = n_actions
        self.learning_rate_dist = learning_rate
        self.graph = tf.Graph()
        with self.graph.as_default():
             self.dis_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.n_actions])
             self.discriminator_function()
             init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        self.sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)
        self.sess.run(init)

    def discriminator_function(self, hidden = None):
         if hidden == None:
             hidden = 16
         x = tf.layers.dense(self.dis_input,hidden,tf.nn.relu)
         x = tf.layers.dense(x,hidden,tf.nn.relu)
         self.dis_output = tf.layers.dense(x,1)


    def discriminator(self,expert_actions,novice_actions):
        expert_out = self.sess.run(self.dis_output,feed_dict={self.dis_input : expert_actions})
        novice_out = self.sess.run(self.dis_output,feed_dict={self.dis_input : novice_actions})
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(expert_out) + tf.log(1.-novice_out))
        # update discriminator loss
        optimize = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate_dis).minimize(-loss)
        self.sess.run(optimize) #error over here
        return loss

if __name__ == '__main__':
     d = discriminator(2,0.001)
     expert_actions = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
     novice_actions = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
     d.discriminator(expert_actions,novice_actions)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to optimize `loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(expert_out) + tf.log(1.-novice_out))` with `expert_out` and `novice_out` being numpy arrays. There are no variables between the input and loss, to compute gradients.

Your discriminator function should be something like this:

```
def discriminator(self,expert_actions,novice_actions):

    #Make sure you add the new ops and variables to the graph defined.  
    with self.graph.as_default(): 
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.log('Should be a tensor that is part of the graph and not a numpy array))

        optimize = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(-loss)

        self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        #pass the inputs here
        loss = self.sess.run([loss, optimize], feed_dict={self.dis_input : expert_actions}) 
        return loss
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the part of the "'Should be a tensor that is part of the graph and not a numpy array" could be self.dis_output? Also where can the `novice_actions` be used in your example?

Comment: yes `self.dis_output` qualifies to be part of the loss. Gradient is computed between two variables given an input. Your trying with one variable with 2 inputs, thats not right.

Comment: Then having a conditional input would perhaps be better? Compute loss separately for `expert_actions` and `novice_actions`?

Comment: I dont think i understand the problem statement. But, like in the case of GANs, where you have two losses: fake one one from generator and the real image, you can have two separate loss functions.